# Scripting: How to correctly group objects

Tags: python, scripting, groups

How can I correctly group multiple objects and have them behave as a unit. I tried the following

```
sceptre = bpy.data.objects['sceptre']
ring = bpy.data.objects['ring']
Group(sceptre,'wizards')
Group(ring,'wizards')
```

**WITH**

```
def Group(obj0,groupName):
    if not groupName in bpy.data.groups:
        bpy.ops.group.create(name=groupName)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj0
    bpy.ops.object.group_link(group=groupName)
```

**AND**

```
def Group(obj0,groupName):
    if not groupName in bpy.data.groups:
        group = bpy.data.groups.new(groupName)
    else:
        group = bpy.data.groups[groupName]
    if not obj0.name in group.objects:
        group.objects.link(obj0)
```

The object property pane shows the new group name for each object under the `Add to Group` tab with the last object outlined in green after running the script but the objects do not move as a unit when I select and drag either of them like it does when manually grouped with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realised I was the one making the mistake, called a blender guru and realised grouped objects didn't move together with the keyboard shortcut so it was just the selection I used to group the objects I was misinterpreting as the group behaviour after I moved the objects together afterwards.

After surfing the web I realised it was either the parenting property or I simply press a keyboard shortcut which brings a dropdown list to choose group and select all objects in it so I can translate at once.